# Convert from Java to Python

Tags: java, python, arrays, list, class

I am new to python and I'm wondering how one would go around to convert a piece of code in this case Java to python. For instance if a public class `Example` is a class which consists of multiple functions for instance:

File 1:

```
public class Example{
    private ArrayList<Something> somethings;
    private boolean test;

    foo(){
            test= false;
            somethings = new ArrayList<>();
        }

.
.
.
```

File 2:

```
class Something{
    private Example another;
    private String whatever;

    Something(String a, Node another){
        this.another = another ;
        this.whatever = whatever;
    }

.
.
.
```

In python what is the equivalent of `import java.util.ArrayList;` and how would one go about it to call another class?

Will this be some sort of the above's equivalent in python? How would I go about linking the 2 classes together in python?

```
class Example():
    def __init__(self):
        self.test= False
        self.somethings= []

.
.
.

class Something:
    def __init__(self, another, whatever):
        self.another = another 
        self.whatever = whatever 
.
.
.
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT 1: My questions mainly are If the implementation of that piece of code are correct and how to call a class within a class in python

EDIT 2:Thanks for everyone who answered so far. Just to clarify with one more thing if I had something like which is in class Example:

```
void exampleSomething(Example exampleb, String a){
        somethings.add(new Something(a, another));
    }
```

in python would this be the following:

```
def exampleSomething(another, a):
    self.somethings.append(a, another)
```

Thanks once again

Comment: Is your question just "What is the equivalent of a a Java `ArrayList` in Python?

Comment: There is no ArrayLists in Python, you only have the List structure by default

Comment: Different questions, my questions mainly are If the implementation of that piece of code are correct and how to call a class within a class in python

Answer (score 4):

Some key differences

- `list` is built-in in python. Just do `x = [1, 2, 3]`
- there is *no private*. By convention, you prefix your "private" variable name by `_`, but nothing can stop others from accessing them.
- inside the class, you *have to use `this`* everywhere. `this` is commonly called `self` in python
- declaring your variables inside the class body (outside methods) makes them class variables, not instance variables (something like `static` in java)

Objects are called just like in java. When  you have a reference to `obj` in another class, just call `obj.f(x)`

Comment: Following my update, how would I go about in adding something like my last edit, i.e. EDIT 2?

Answer (score 1):

```java
import java.util.Random;

/**
 *
 * @author Vijini
 */

//Main class
public class SimpleDemoGA {

    Population population = new Population();
    Individual fittest;
    Individual secondFittest;
    int generationCount = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random rn = new Random();

        SimpleDemoGA demo = new SimpleDemoGA();

        //Initialize population
        demo.population.initializePopulation(10);

        //Calculate fitness of each individual
        demo.population.calculateFitness();

        System.out.println("Generation: " + demo.generationCount + " Fittest: " + demo.population.fittest);

        //While population gets an individual with maximum fitness
        while (demo.population.fittest < 5) {
            ++demo.generationCount;

            //Do selection
            demo.selection();

            //Do crossover
            demo.crossover();

            //Do mutation under a random probability
            if (rn.nextInt()%7 < 5) {
                demo.mutation();
            }

            //Add fittest offspring to population
            demo.addFittestOffspring();

            //Calculate new fitness value
            demo.population.calculateFitness();

            System.out.println("Generation: " + demo.generationCount + " Fittest: " + demo.population.fittest);
        }

        System.out.println("\nSolution found in generation " + demo.generationCount);
        System.out.println("Fitness: "+demo.population.getFittest().fitness);
        System.out.print("Genes: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.print(demo.population.getFittest().genes[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("");

    }

    //Selection
    void selection() {

        //Select the most fittest individual
        fittest = population.getFittest();

        //Select the second most fittest individual
        secondFittest = population.getSecondFittest();
    }

    //Crossover
    void crossover() {
        Random rn = new Random();

        //Select a random crossover point
        int crossOverPoint = rn.nextInt(population.individuals[0].geneLength);

        //Swap values among parents
        for (int i = 0; i < crossOverPoint; i++) {
            int temp = fittest.genes[i];
            fittest.genes[i] = secondFittest.genes[i];
            secondFittest.genes[i] = temp;

        }

    }

    //Mutation
    void mutation() {
        Random rn = new Random();

        //Select a random mutation point
        int mutationPoint = rn.nextInt(population.individuals[0].geneLength);

        //Flip values at the mutation point
        if (fittest.genes[mutationPoint] == 0) {
            fittest.genes[mutationPoint] = 1;
        } else {
            fittest.genes[mutationPoint] = 0;
        }

        mutationPoint = rn.nextInt(population.individuals[0].geneLength);

        if (secondFittest.genes[mutationPoint] == 0) {
            secondFittest.genes[mutationPoint] = 1;
        } else {
            secondFittest.genes[mutationPoint] = 0;
        }
    }

    //Get fittest offspring
    Individual getFittestOffspring() {
        if (fittest.fitness > secondFittest.fitness) {
            return fittest;
        }
        return secondFittest;
    }


    //Replace least fittest individual from most fittest offspring
    void addFittestOffspring() {

        //Update fitness values of offspring
        fittest.calcFitness();
        secondFittest.calcFitness();

        //Get index of least fit individual
        int leastFittestIndex = population.getLeastFittestIndex();

        //Replace least fittest individual from most fittest offspring
        population.individuals[leastFittestIndex] = getFittestOffspring();
    }

}


//Individual class
class Individual {

    int fitness = 0;
    int[] genes = new int[5];
    int geneLength = 5;

    public Individual() {
        Random rn = new Random();

        //Set genes randomly for each individual
        for (int i = 0; i < genes.length; i++) {
            genes[i] = Math.abs(rn.nextInt() % 2);
        }

        fitness = 0;
    }

    //Calculate fitness
    public void calcFitness() {

        fitness = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (genes[i] == 1) {
                ++fitness;
            }
        }
    }

}

//Population class
class Population {

    int popSize = 10;
    Individual[] individuals = new Individual[10];
    int fittest = 0;

    //Initialize population
    public void initializePopulation(int size) {
        for (int i = 0; i < individuals.length; i++) {
            individuals[i] = new Individual();
        }
    }

    //Get the fittest individual
    public Individual getFittest() {
        int maxFit = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int maxFitIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < individuals.length; i++) {
            if (maxFit <= individuals[i].fitness) {
                maxFit = individuals[i].fitness;
                maxFitIndex = i;
            }
        }
        fittest = individuals[maxFitIndex].fitness;
        return individuals[maxFitIndex];
    }

    //Get the second most fittest individual
    public Individual getSecondFittest() {
        int maxFit1 = 0;
        int maxFit2 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < individuals.length; i++) {
            if (individuals[i].fitness > individuals[maxFit1].fitness) {
                maxFit2 = maxFit1;
                maxFit1 = i;
            } else if (individuals[i].fitness > individuals[maxFit2].fitness) {
                maxFit2 = i;
            }
        }
        return individuals[maxFit2];
    }

    //Get index of least fittest individual
    public int getLeastFittestIndex() {
        int minFitVal = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int minFitIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < individuals.length; i++) {
            if (minFitVal >= individuals[i].fitness) {
                minFitVal = individuals[i].fitness;
                minFitIndex = i;
            }
        }
        return minFitIndex;
    }

    //Calculate fitness of each individual
    public void calculateFitness() {

        for (int i = 0; i < individuals.length; i++) {
            individuals[i].calcFitness();
        }
        getFittest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To import a class in `Python`, if the class is to be in a separate file, just use :

```
import fileName
```

at the beginning of you second file

In your case, you would :

```
import example
```

Comment: Great thanks! And how would you call the class instance?

Comment: you would just have to do `x = Example()` similar to Java

Comment: Following my update, how would I go about in adding something like my last edit, i.e. EDIT 2?

Comment: Yes, that seems fine

Answer (score 0):

Let's see:

```
class Example():
    def __init__(self):
        self.test= False
        self.somethings= []

.
.
.

class Something:
    def __init__(self, another, whatever):
        self.another = another 
        self.whatever = whatever 
.
.
.
```

Should be fine. But all your class members are public. Let's make them private:

```
class Example():
    def __init__(self):
        self._test= False
        self._somethings= []

.
.
.

class Something:
    def __init__(self, another, whatever):
        self._another = another 
        self._whatever = whatever 
.
.
.
```

To add getters and setters checkout the `@property` decorator: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/property

Now, do you want types? In python 3+ you can have types: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

```
class Example():
    def __init__(self):
        self._test= False
        self._somethings= []

.
.
.

class Something:
    def __init__(self, another -> str, whatever -> Node):
        self._another = another 
        self._whatever = whatever 
.
.
.
```

And `ArrayList` becomes just `list()` - a builtin type that's available everywhere.

Comment: Following my update, how would I go about in adding something like my last edit, i.e. EDIT 2?

Comment: `self.somethings.append(Someting(a, another))` You use the class name with `()` after it to call the constructor.